# Merging data.tables containing date columns with rbindlist

Tags: r, data.table

Here are two `data.table` objects :

```
a <- data.table(v1=today(), v2=seq(1, 5))
b <- data.table(v2=seq(6, 10))
```

When I want to combine them with the `rbindlist` function, everything goes well if the first element of my `list` is `a`, but I get an error message if the first element of my `list` is `b`.

```
> rbindlist(list(a, b), fill=TRUE)
            v1 v2
 1: 2017-10-11  1
 2: 2017-10-11  2
 3: 2017-10-11  3
 4: 2017-10-11  4
 5: 2017-10-11  5
 6:       <NA>  6
 7:       <NA>  7
 8:       <NA>  8
 9:       <NA>  9
10:       <NA> 10

> rbindlist(list(b, a), fill=TRUE)
Error in rbindlist(list(b, a), fill = TRUE) : 
  Class attributes at column 2 of input list at position 2 does not match with column 2 of
  input list at position 1. Coercion of objects of class 'factor' alone is handled
  internally by rbind/rbindlist at the moment.
```

I thought I would get the exact same result, except that rows 1 to 5 and rows 6 to 10 would be interchanged.

Can anybody explain me why? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: For me it is working fine.  What is your data.table version?

Comment: I have version 1.9.6 installed and A LOT of dependencies on other projects...!

Comment: It is an older version.  That explains it.  I am using `data.table_1.10.5`

Comment: You should minimize the dependencies and be explicit about them when building an example. R has no `today` function, for example. Also 1.9.6 is kind of old so you might want to update if you can.